# Spyder- 'invalid filepath' at selection of python environment

Tags: python, conda, spyder, pythoninterpreter

so, I am new as active member here.

But now...a real problem to be solved:
Under Windows10, I have installed some python version (3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11) with miniconda (it uses python3.9), just for me as user, every of them in its own virt. evironment.

So, same i did with Spyder 5.1, 5.2, 5.4.
[Virt. environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUmcm.jpg)

Now, i tried to select the various pythons via Tools-> Preferences -> Interpreter within Spyder 5.1
I was a little suprised, that only 2 of them were accepted by Spyder.
Python 3.8 and 3.10 were accepted, while 3.9 and 3.11 causes this error message:
[Spyder error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhkBS.jpg).

I think, this is a real problem of spyder, because intelliJ accepted all of my virtual python environments.
I do not know really, what to do and where to do, to make Spyder work with all the different python environments.

To the audience:
Did you make such a experience too?
Any ideas how to solve it?
Is this problem known to Spyder?

Try and error method with Spyder5.1 and 5.3 and the different python environments.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)